# Matplotlib animation init_func first frame

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, networkx

I would like to create an animation that shows how the structure of a network changes over time. I am using matplotlib as well as networkx. I am having trouble getting the following toy example to work.

Suppose I have a graph that is just four nodes connected in a line. I want my animation to do the following: the very first frame should show the entire line of nodes. Afterwards, every frame should show the first node of the line, the first two nodes connected in a line, etc.

Here is my initial attempt:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('agg')
import pylab
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import animation

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(0)
pos = {}
pos[0] = (0, 0)
labels = {}
labels[0] = '0'
for i in xrange(1, 5):
    G.add_node(i)
    pos[i] = (0, i)
    labels[i] = str(i)
    G.add_edge(i - 1, i)

fig = pylab.figure()
left = right = top = bottom = None

def init():
    nx.draw(G, pos=pos, labels=labels)
    ax = pylab.gca()
    global left, right, top, bottom
    left, right = ax.get_xlim()
    bottom, top = ax.get_ylim()
    pylab.savefig('network_changes_init.png', format='png')

def redraw(frame):
    pylab.clf()
    nbunch = range(frame + 1)
    D = G.subgraph(nbunch)
    pos2 = {}
    labels2 = {}
    for u in D.nodes():
        pos2[u] = pos[u]
        labels2[u] = labels[u]
    nx.draw(D, pos=pos2, labels=labels2)
    pylab.xlim(left, right)
    pylab.ylim(bottom, top)
    pylab.savefig('network_changes%d.png' % frame, format='png')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, redraw, init_func=init, frames=4)
ani.save('network_changes.mp4', writer='avconv')
```

This code runs without errors, however it does not produce the animation I want. There should be five total frames: the initial frame (drawn according the function init()) and four additional frames (drawn according to the function redraw()). Instead there are only four frames: the four frames drawn by redraw. It does not draw the initial frame that I want.

Here are the four frames that are part of the animation

frame 1
[image]

frame2
[image]

frame3
[image]

frame4
[image]

What I want is for the first frame to look like this (which is what is drawn in the function init())

[image]

I know for a fact that init() is being called, because the global variables left, right, top, and bottom are being set in it. But why is the drawing that is made in this function not being added to the final animation?

Comment: I am pretty puzzled by your code, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. My guess is that your problem is that you are clearing the figure (`clf()`) at the beginning of each `redraw()`, so whatever is drawn by `init()` is being immediately erased.

Comment: I have a graph with 4 nodes in a line, I want an animation with five frames: frame 1 (init_func) should show the full graph, and each subsequent frame should show the first k nodes in the line. I realize I could ignore init_func and hard-code this into redraw, but I would like to know why what I draw in init_func doesn't make it into the final animation. I also suspect it's due to using clf() but I am hoping to get confirmation.